# Why I can not use "p->data" instead of "head->data" in C?

Tags: c, pointers, dereference

```
typedef struct DNode{
    int data;
    struct DNode *lLink,*rLink;
} DblNode;
typedef DblNode * DblList;

void DestroyDblList(DblList L){
    DblList head=L;
    DblList p=head->rLink;
    if(head->data){ //p->data is wrong?
        while(p->data){
            free(head);
            head=p;
            p=head->rLink;
         }
         free(head);
    }
}
```

At the line with comments, when I use `if(p->data){` my computer tells me

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

but when I use `if(head->data){` it is OK.

How did it happen,what is the cause of it?

Comment: `p` and `head` are different pointers. why you expect them to have the same behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code `p->data` is same as `head->rLink->data`, where `head->rLink` is not allocated memory. So, segmentation fault [as a side effect of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).].

On other hand, `head->data` is a perfect access.

BTW, you understand that `p->data` and `head->data` are not *same* [at line `56`], right?

Answer (score 1):

`p->data` and `head->data` would be the same if `p` and `head` would be the same. In line 56 this can only be true if `head` is the same as `head->rLink` by line 55, i.e. `head` points to itself which contradicts the understanding of a double linked list.

So `p->data` and `head->data` must be different.

Answer (score 0):

You should test the nullity of `p`, not `p->data`.

Comment: I thought about this one, too, and came to the conclusion that there are scenarios in which `p->data` is correct. Besides this doesn't answer the question IMHO.